# how to store image data in X server in gtk, gdk?

Tags: gtk, x11, gdk

Is there anyway to store image data in X server memory so that rendering of images, (for example in scrolling), is faster and so that round trips to x client can be reduced?

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured out how to do it. we can use a backing pixmap or we can also copy parts of the window directly to drawables using the function call gdk_draw_drawable(). Using pixmap will store the image data on the server side and hence will reduce the number of round trips to the client